Problem with testing pda contract
ive tried everything and the code that im trying to deploy for the test is not working...
This is the lib.rs:
#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("AsjZ3kWAUSQRNt2pZVeJkywhZ6gpLpHZmJjduPmKZDZZ");

#[program]
pub mod grasschain_contract {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_contract(
        ctx: Context<CreateContract>,
        investment_amount: u64,
        yield_percentage: u8,
        duration: i64
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let contract = &mut ctx.accounts.contract;
        contract.farmer_id = ctx.accounts.farmer.key();
        contract.investor_id = None;
        contract.start_date = None;
        contract.end_date = None;
        contract.status = ContractStatus::Created;
        contract.investment_amount = investment_amount;
        contract.yield_percentage = yield_percentage;
        contract.duration = duration;

        msg!("Contract created by farmer: {}", ctx.accounts.farmer.key());
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn fund_contract(ctx: Context<FundContract>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let contract = &mut ctx.accounts.contract;

        require!(
            contract.status == ContractStatus::Created,
            ErrorCode::InvalidContractStatus
        );

        // Check that the investor provides exactly the required amount
        require!(
            amount == contract.investment_amount,
            ErrorCode::InvalidInvestmentAmount
        );

        contract.investor_id = Some(ctx.accounts.investor.key());
        contract.start_date = Some(Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp);
        contract.end_date = Some(Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp + contract.duration);
        contract.status = ContractStatus::Active;

        msg!(
            "Contract funded by investor: {} with amount: {}, start_date: {}, end_date: {}",
            ctx.accounts.investor.key(),
            amount,
            contract.start_date.unwrap(),
            contract.end_date.unwrap()
        );

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn settle_contract(ctx: Context<SettleContract>, buyback_amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let contract = &mut ctx.accounts.contract;

        require!(
            contract.status == ContractStatus::Active,
            ErrorCode::InvalidContractStatus
        );

        let current_time = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;
        require!(
            current_time >= contract.end_date.unwrap(),
            ErrorCode::ContractNotFinished
        );

        let required_buyback = contract.calculate_buyback();
        require!(
            buyback_amount >= required_buyback,
            ErrorCode::InsufficientBuyback
        );

        contract.status = ContractStatus::Settled;

        msg!("Contract settled by farmer: {}, buyback: {}", contract.farmer_id, buyback_amount);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[account]
pub struct Contract {
    pub farmer_id: Pubkey,
    pub investor_id: Option<Pubkey>,
    pub investment_amount: u64,
    pub duration: i64,
    pub yield_percentage: u8,
    pub start_date: Option<i64>,
    pub end_date: Option<i64>,
    pub status: ContractStatus,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum ContractStatus {
    Created,
    Active,
    Settled,
}

impl Contract {
    pub fn calculate_buyback(&self) -> u64 {
        self.investment_amount + (self.investment_amount * self.yield_percentage as u64) / 100
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateContract<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = farmer,
        space = 8 + 128, 
        seeds = [b"contract", farmer.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub contract: Account<'info, Contract>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub farmer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct FundContract<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub contract: Account<'info, Contract>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub investor: Signer<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SettleContract<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub contract: Account<'info, Contract>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub farmer: Signer<'info>,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Invalid contract status")]
    InvalidContractStatus,
    #[msg("Invalid investment amount")]
    InvalidInvestmentAmount,
    #[msg("Contract not finished yet")]
    ContractNotFinished,
    #[msg("Insufficient buyback amount")]
    InsufficientBuyback,
}

This is the test contract:
import { PublicKey, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { BN, Provider } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { ProgramTestContext, startAnchor } from 'solana-bankrun';
import { BankrunProvider } from 'anchor-bankrun';
import { BanksClient } from 'solana-bankrun';
import { Program } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { GrasschainContract } from '../target/types/grasschain_contract';

describe("GrassChain Contract Tests", () => {
  let context: ProgramTestContext;
  let provider: BankrunProvider;
  let program: Program<GrasschainContract>;
  let banksClient: BanksClient;

  let farmer: Keypair;
  let contractKey: PublicKey;

  // Contract parameters
  const investmentAmount = new BN(1_000_000_000); // 1 SOL equivalent
  const yieldPercentage = 10;
  const duration = new BN(180); // 3 minutes in seconds

  beforeAll(async () => {
    // Start the test context with the grasschain_contract program
    context = await startAnchor(
      "",
      [{ name: "grasschain_contract", programId: new PublicKey("AsjZ3kWAUSQRNt2pZVeJkywhZ6gpLpHZmJjduPmKZDZZ") }],
      []
    );

    provider = new BankrunProvider(context);
    anchor.setProvider(provider as Provider);

    // Load the GrasschainContract program
    program = new Program<GrasschainContract>(
      require('../target/idl/grasschain_contract.json'),
      provider as Provider
    );
    banksClient = context.banksClient;

    farmer = provider.wallet.payer;

    // Derive the PDA for `contract`
    [contractKey] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("contract"), farmer.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );
  });

  it("Creates a contract with farmer input", async () => {
    await program.methods
      .createContract(investmentAmount, yieldPercentage, duration)
      .accounts({
        farmer: farmer.publicKey,
        **contract**: contractKey,
        system_program: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })      
      .signers([])
      .rpc({ commitment: "confirmed" });

    const contractData = await program.account.contract.fetch(contractKey);
    console.log("Contract created:", contractData);

    expect(contractData.investmentAmount.toNumber()).toBe(investmentAmount.toNumber());
    expect(contractData.yieldPercentage).toBe(yieldPercentage);

    // Since ContractStatus is an enum, check the variant name
    // The IDL maps enums to lowercase variant names, so we check "created"
    expect(Object.keys(contractData.status)[0]).toBe("created");
  });
});

The problem gets highlighted in contract and the analyzer tells me this:
The object literal can only specify known properties, and 'contract' does not exist in the type 'ResolvedAccounts<{ name: "contract"; writable: true; pda: { seeds: [{ kind: "const"; value: [99, 111, 110, 116, 114, 97, 99, 116]; }, { kind: "account"; path: "farmer"; }]; }; } | { name: "farmer"; writable: true; signer: true; } | { ...; }>'.


This is related to the account resolution change made in anchor 0.30.0
To fix call the method using the accountStrict method that will require all account to be passed in i.e
// -- snip

 .accountsStrict({
        farmer: farmer.publicKey,
        **contract**: contractKey,
        system_program: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })  

// -- snip

Or as per documentation

remove all accounts that can be resolved from the IDL. For example:


- await program.methods
-   .init()
-   .accounts({
-     pda: ...,
-     signer: ...,
-     systemProgram: ...,
-   })
-   .rpc();

+ await program.methods.init().rpc();

